# plot histogram and pdf in same plot for poisson

Tags: r, histogram, poisson

I have a dataset which i need to analyse with poisson regression. 
I try to plot the histrogram of the respons in the same plot as the pdf but i don't find how..

i plot my histogram with the following code:

```
library(lattice) 
tot <- mydata[, 1] 
histogram(tot)
```

and get a nice histogram. To add the pdf i've tried some codes lie the one below:

```
xlines <-seq(min(tot),max(tot),length.out=100)  
lines(x = xlines,y=dpois(xlines,21))
```

I've tried a few other codes as well but can't find one that works... 
 
Somebody has some suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start working on this code:

```
library(lattice) 
set.seed(1)
tot <- rpois(100,21)
xlines <- seq(min(tot),max(tot),by=1)
histogram(tot, type="density", 
  panel=function(x, ...){
    panel.histogram(x,...)
    panel.lines(x = xlines, y=dpois(xlines,21), lwd=2, col="red")
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i think Your question is in general incorrect as far as it makes little sense to plot histogram and pdf together (the coordinates of frequency histogram and density plot are different). What You can do is to ask R to plot histogram in probability coordinates. Here is little example on iris dataset.

```
data=iris
x=iris[, 1]
hist(x, freq=F)
lines(density(x))
```

What gives You:[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IqIL3.png)

Compare to what You were doing before:

```
data=iris
x <- iris[, 1]
hist(x, freq=T)
lines(density(x))
```

Hope it helps!